# Composed sorting of template parameters

Tags: c++, sorting, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

To sort a pack of template integers,

```
template <int...> struct sequence;

int main() {
    using Sequence = sequence<3,6,1,0,9,5,4,7,2,8>;
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        sort<int, Sequence, less_than>::type,
        sequence<0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9>
    >::value, "");
}
```

we can use the following implementation (tested on GCC 5.3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace meta {
    template <typename T, T, typename> struct prepend;

    template <typename T, T Add, template <T...> class Z, T... Is>  
    struct prepend<T, Add, Z<Is...>> {  
        using type = Z<Add, Is...>;  
    };

    template <typename T, typename Pack1, typename Pack2> struct concat;

    template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T... Ts, T... Us>
    struct concat<T, Z<Ts...>, Z<Us...>> {
        using type = Z<Ts..., Us...>;
    };
}

template <int I, int J>
struct less_than : std::conditional<(I < J), std::true_type, std::false_type>::type {};

template <typename T, typename Pack, template <T, T> class = less_than> struct sort;  

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, template <T, T> class Comparator>  
struct sort<T, Z<>, Comparator> {  
    using type = Z<>;
};

template <typename T, typename Pack, template<T> class UnaryPredicate> struct filter;  

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, template<T> class UnaryPredicate, T I, T... Is>  
struct filter<T, Z<I, Is...>, UnaryPredicate> {
    using type = typename std::conditional<UnaryPredicate<I>::value,
        typename meta::prepend<T, I, typename filter<T, Z<Is...>, UnaryPredicate>::type>::type,
        typename filter<T, Z<Is...>, UnaryPredicate>::type
    >::type;  
};

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, template<T> class UnaryPredicate>  
struct filter<T, Z<>, UnaryPredicate> {  
    using type = Z<>;  
};  

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T N, T... Is, template <T, T> class Comparator>  
struct sort<T, Z<N, Is...>, Comparator> {  // Using the quicksort method.
    template <T I> struct less_than : std::integral_constant<bool, Comparator<I,N>::value> {};
    template <T I> struct more_than : std::integral_constant<bool, !Comparator<I,N>::value> {};  
    using subsequence_less_than_N = typename filter<T, Z<Is...>, less_than>::type;
    using subsequence_more_than_N = typename filter<T, Z<Is...>, more_than>::type; 
    using type = typename meta::concat<T, typename sort<T, subsequence_less_than_N, Comparator>::type,  
        typename meta::prepend<T, N, typename sort<T, subsequence_more_than_N, Comparator>::type>::type 
    >::type;
};

// Testing
template <int...> struct sequence;

int main() {
    using Sequence = sequence<3,6,1,0,9,5,4,7,2,8>;
    static_assert(std::is_same<
        sort<int, Sequence, less_than>::type,
        sequence<0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9>
    >::value, "");
}
```

Now suppose we want to compose several binary predicates to get the sorting.  For example:

```
 25 placed first before anything else.
 16 to be placed after everything else.
 Even numbers placed after all 25's, if any, have been placed (and the even numbers sorted in increasing value among themselves).
 After these order on ascending last digit, except that last digit 7 appears before other last digits.
 If last digits are equal, order by increasing value.
```

I want to implement `composed_sort` using something like:

```
template <typename T, T, T, template <T, T> class...> struct composed_binary_predicates;

template <typename T, T A, T B, template <T, T> class Comparator, template <T, T> class... Rest>
struct composed_binary_predicates<T, A, B, Comparator, Rest...> : std::conditional_t<
    Comparator<A,B>::value,
    std::true_type,
    std::conditional_t<
        Comparator<B,A>::value,
        std::false_type,
        composed_binary_predicates<T, A, B, Rest...>
    >
> {};

template <typename T, T A, T B, template <T, T> class Comparator>
struct composed_binary_predicates<T, A, B, Comparator> : Comparator<A,B> {};
```

So we have a pack of binary predicates being used.  If the first one `Comparator` has `Comparator<A,B>::value == true`, then value is true, if `Comparator<B,A>::value == true`, then value is false, else check the next predicate, and so forth.  This composition of binary predicates will be used to carry out the sort.  So `sort` itself I tried to modify to the following:

```
template <typename T, typename Sequence,
    template <typename U, U, U, template <U,U> class...> class Comparator,
    template <T, T> class... Preds> struct composed_sort;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T N, T... Is, template <typename U, U, U, template <U,U> class...> class Comparator, template <T, T> class... Preds>  
struct composed_sort<T, Z<N, Is...>, Comparator, Preds...> {
    template <T I> struct less_than : std::integral_constant<bool, Comparator<T,I,N, Preds...>::value> {};
    template <T I> struct more_than : std::integral_constant<bool, !Comparator<T,I,N, Preds...>::value> {};  
    using subsequence_less_than_N = typename filter<T, Z<Is...>, less_than>::type;
    using subsequence_more_than_N = typename filter<T, Z<Is...>, more_than>::type; 
    using type = typename meta::concat<T, typename composed_sort<T, subsequence_less_than_N, Comparator, Preds...>::type,  
        typename meta::prepend<T, N, typename composed_sort<T, subsequence_more_than_N, Comparator, Preds...>::type>::type 
    >::type;
};
```

which can then be used as

```
composed_sort<int, Sequence, composed_binary_predicates, Predicates...>::type
```

But GCC 5.3 gets internal compiler error and thus cannot handle the code.  Is there a workaround, or a simpler implementation altogether, to get the job done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class T, template<T,T> class C>
struct zComp {
  template<T a, T b>
  using result=C<a,b>;
  using type=T;
};

template<class C0, class...Cs>
struct compose_comparators;

template<class C0>
struct compose_comparators<C0>:C0{};

template<class C0, class C1, class...Cs>
struct compose_comparators<C0, C1, Cs...> {
  using type=typename C0::type;
private:
  template<type a, type b>
  using r0 = typename C0::template result<a,b>;
  template<type a, type b>
  using r1 = typename compose_comparators<C1, Cs...>::template result<a,b>;
public:
  template<type a, type b>
  using result = std::conditional_t<
    (r0<a,b>::value || r0<b,a>::value),
    r0<a,b>,
    r1<a,b>
  >;
};
```

To use the above, take your predicates, wrap them in `zComp`.  When you don't care, return `false` on both `a,b` and `b,a`.

Feed your raw `X<int,int>` comparators to `zComp<int, X>` -- you can change the above to work with packs of templates, but I have a bias for working with types in my metaprogramming, so I package up the templates into `zComp`s.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd6389db0845cab9).

Oh, another useful trick -- make `sequence {}` have an empty `{}` body.  Then you can use assignment as a better-debug-message "`is_same`" test, because you are told what the lhs and rhs types are and that they are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I worked around the compiler problems with my first method, and got my desired syntax working : `composed_sort<T, Sequence, Predicates...>::type`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

namespace meta {
    template <typename T, T, typename> struct prepend;

    template <typename T, T Add, template <T...> class Z, T... Is>  
    struct prepend<T, Add, Z<Is...>> {  
        using type = Z<Add, Is...>;  
    };

    template <typename T, typename Pack1, typename Pack2> struct concat;

    template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T... Ts, T... Us>
    struct concat<T, Z<Ts...>, Z<Us...>> {
        using type = Z<Ts..., Us...>;
    };
}

template <typename T, typename Pack, template <T> class UnaryPredicate> struct filter;  

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, template <T> class UnaryPredicate, T I, T... Is>  
struct filter<T, Z<I, Is...>, UnaryPredicate> : std::conditional_t<UnaryPredicate<I>::value,
    meta::prepend<T, I, typename filter<T, Z<Is...>, UnaryPredicate>::type>,
    filter<T, Z<Is...>, UnaryPredicate>
> {};

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, template <T> class UnaryPredicate>  
struct filter<T, Z<>, UnaryPredicate> {  
    using type = Z<>;  
};

template <typename T, T A, T B, template <T, T> class Comparator, template <T, T> class... Rest>
struct composed_binary_predicates : std::conditional_t<
    Comparator<A,B>::value,
    std::true_type,
    std::conditional_t<
        Comparator<B,A>::value,
        std::false_type,
        composed_binary_predicates<T, A, B, Rest...>
    >
> {};

template <typename T, T A, T B, template <T, T> class Comparator>
struct composed_binary_predicates<T, A, B, Comparator> : Comparator<A,B> {};

template <typename T, typename Sequence, template <T, T> class... Preds> struct composed_sort;

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, T N, T... Is, template <T, T> class... Predicates>  
struct composed_sort<T, Z<N, Is...>, Predicates...> {  // Using the quick sort method.
    template <T I> struct less_than : std::integral_constant<bool, composed_binary_predicates<T,I,N, Predicates...>::value> {};
    template <T I> struct more_than : std::integral_constant<bool, !composed_binary_predicates<T,I,N, Predicates...>::value> {};  
    using subsequence_less_than_N = typename filter<T, Z<Is...>, less_than>::type;
    using subsequence_more_than_N = typename filter<T, Z<Is...>, more_than>::type; 
    using type = typename meta::concat<T, typename composed_sort<T, subsequence_less_than_N, Predicates...>::type,  
        typename meta::prepend<T, N, typename composed_sort<T, subsequence_more_than_N, Predicates...>::type>::type 
    >::type;
};

template <typename T, template <T...> class Z, template <T, T> class... Predicates>  
struct composed_sort<T, Z<>, Predicates...> {  
    using type = Z<>;
};

// Testing
template <int...> struct sequence;

template <int I, int J>  // The standard less than.
struct less_than : std::conditional_t<(I < J), std::true_type, std::false_type> {};

template <int N>
struct N_first {
    template <int I, int J>
    struct result : std::conditional_t<(I == N && J != N), std::true_type, std::false_type> {};
};

template <int I, int J>  // 25 placed first before anything else.
using twentyfive_first = typename N_first<25>::template result<I,J>;

template <int N>
struct N_last {
    template <int I, int J>
    struct result : std::conditional_t<(I != N && J == N), std::true_type, std::false_type> {};
};

template <int I, int J>  // 16 to be placed after everything else.
using sixteen_last = typename N_last<16>::template result<I,J>;

template <int I, int J>  // Even numbers placed after all 25's, if any, have been placed (and the even numbers sorted in increasing value among themselves).
struct even_numbers : std::conditional_t<((I%2 == 0 && J%2 != 0) || (I%2 == 0 && J%2 == 0 && I < J)), std::true_type, std::false_type> {}; 

int main() {
    using Sequence = sequence<16,3,6,16,1,0,9,5,4,16,25,7,2,8,25>;
    static_assert (std::is_same<
        composed_sort<int, Sequence, less_than>::type,
        sequence<0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,16,16,16,25,25>
    >::value, "");
    static_assert (std::is_same<
        composed_sort<int, Sequence, twentyfive_first, sixteen_last, even_numbers, less_than>::type,
        sequence<25,25,0,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,7,9,16,16,16>
    >::value, "");
}
```

Main disadvantage with this implementation:  Neglects the DRY principle, as now the structs `sort` and `composed_sort` are basically repeating each other.
Arguably, the nice-looking syntax of `composed_sort<T, Sequence, Predicates...>::type` does not really offset this violation of the DRY principle.
Yakk's method is definitely better.